# crossfilter dc.barChart renders empty chart without bars

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am plotting a crossfilter bar chart with dimensions having dates. From my ground knowledge, the x axis is the dim, and I have used the date as my dim. But the chart is empty.

I have checked the varGroup.size() which returns 6 as expected since the data spans over 6 days and I have parsed date to be in days.

```js
var varCountDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.created_at;} );
var varCountGroup = varCountDim.group( function (d) {if (d.length) return d; })
var minDate = varCountDim.bottom(1)[0].created_at;
var maxDate = varCountDim.top(1)[0].created_at;
var dateChart = dc.barChart("#date-chart");


dateChart
.width(780)
.height(400)
.margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 40})
.dimension(varCountDim)
.group(varCountGroup)
.transitionDuration(500)
.x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
.elasticY(true)
.xUnits(function(){return 20;})
.yAxis().ticks(4);
 dateChart.render();
```

The contents of varCountGroup are :

[image]

Expected results is a bar chart with date on the x axis and varcount on the y axis. The only thing appears are the axes lines and no bars

Comment: Please don't post questions multiple times. Close this or the other one, please?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is that you are using a time scale but have not converted your date strings to date objects.

Although you could do this in the dimension key function, it's more efficient to do this before initializing crossfilter.

This would look something like

```
var parse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.created_at = parse(d.created_at);
});
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
```

Comment: I have done that but it returns null.. With my version of d3 3.5.17 , this is how I do the parsing to datetime  `var dparse = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: I have done that but it returns null.. With my version of d3 3.5.17 , this is how I do the parsing to datetime  `var dparse = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d")
d.created_at = dparse.parse(d.created_at)` but it returns a null value. ..so this is what works 
`dparse = d3.time.format("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y").parse
d.created_at = dparse(d.created_at)`

Comment: Right, under D3v3 you need to use the [.parse()](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md#parse) method of the  [d3.time.format](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md#format) function object. Thanks for following up!